# Usage of go/parser across packages

Tags: parsing, go, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I have used [go/parser](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) to parse a golang file and examine it's AST. I have a specific problem for which I want to use go/parser but I hit a roadblock.

Consider that the following files are present in GOPATH/src

```
$GOPATH/src/
    example.go
    example_package/
        example_package.go
```

The following are the contents of the files above

**example.go**

```
package main

import (
    "example_package"
)

type MyObject struct {
    base *example_package.BaseObject
}

func DoMyThing(arg *example_package.FirstArg) {
    arg.Write(10)
}

func DoMyAnotherThing() {
}

func main() {
    example_package.GetItStarted(&MyObject{})
}
```

**example_package.go**

```
package example_package

func GetItStarted(obj interface{}) {
}

type FirstArg interface {
    Read() int
    Write(x int)
}

type BaseObject struct {
}

func (p *BaseObject) DoSomething(arg *FirstArg, a int) {
    arg.Write(arg.Read() + a)
}
```

My intention is to write a go program called `gen_structure` that is used like this

```
$ gen_structure example.go
```

The output would be

```
> MyObject
- DoMyThing(arg)
- base
    - DoSomething(arg, a)
```

**What did gen_structure do?**

It parses example.go and

1. Extracts "MyObject" from the line `example_package.GetItStarted(&MyObject{})` from inside the main() function.
2. Looks for methods on `MyObject` that have atleast one argument with the first one being of type `*package_example.FirstArg`. It finds `DoMyThing` (and ignored `DoMyAnotherThing`).
3. Identifies the member `base` and peeks inside (by opening the `example_package`).
4. Applies the same process to find methods as above and finds `DoSomething`
5. Using the collected information, it prints the required output.

I understand I can parse a single file or a bunch of files in the same directory using the functionality within `go/parser`. However, I am unable to figure out how to resolve symbols across packages (In this case, `example_package`).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [ast.NewPackage](http://godoc.org/go/ast#NewPackage) to resolve a package names.  You will need to supply an [importer](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Importer) that returns an [*ast.Object](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Object) for the given import path. If all you want to do is resolve the name to a path, the importer can simply return an [*ast.Object](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Object) with the [Kind](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Object.Kind) set to [ast.Pkg](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Pkg) and the [Name](http://godoc.org/go/ast#Object.Name) set to name of the package. Most of the heavy lifting in the importer can be done with the [go/build](http://godoc.org/go/build) package.  If want to resolve do the AST for the target package, you will need to parse the package and return the ast.Object for the package. To prevent loading the same package multiple times, use the map argument to the importer as a cache of previously loaded packages.

Here's some untested code for finding the resolved package path from the `*ast.SelectorExpr` `se`:

```
    if x, _ := se.X.(*ast.Ident); x != nil {
        if obj := x.Obj; obj != nil && obj.Kind == ast.Pkg {
            if spec, _ := obj.Decl.(*ast.ImportSpec); spec != nil {
                if path, err := strconv.Unquote(spec.Path.Value); err == nil {
                    // path is resolved path for selector expression se.
                }
            }
         }
     }
```

The [go/types](http://godoc.org/go/types) package can also be used to get this information and more.  I recommend using go/types instead of using go/ast directly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to attempt an implementation based on the above.

Comment: They are different importers.  The `ast.Importer` is simple: Call the go/build import function to get a `*build.Package` and return `&ast.Object{Kind: ast.Pkg, Name: p.Name}` where `p` is the `*build.Package`.  I would use go/types instead of go/ast. The problem described in the question is at the limit of what one can do with the go/ast package.  The code will probably be shorter if you use go/types instead of go/ast directly.